# Titanium Webview Component Automatically Increases Fontsize

Tags: webview, titanium, font-size

Whatever I do it keeps increasing font sizes automatically on rows in the document I open.

Is there any way to keep font sizes intact?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: On which kind of device are you testing ? Android ?

Comment: do you have any code to show/reproduce? Implement it here: http://tifiddle.com/

Comment: function webpencere(e){
 var self = Ti.UI.createWebView();
 
 self.scalesPageToFit = false;
 self.backgroundColor = "#72bdf4";
 
 return self;
}

Comment: My app is on both iOS and Android. Can be found in stores;

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aves.trd

And you can search with 'trs aves' on App Store.

Touch menu icon upper left and choose 'YAYIN KURULU' scroll down. You'll see the names below 'Yayın Koordinatörleri' automatically increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh... welcome to Titanium.

In our framework [Trimethyl](https://github.com/CaffeinaLab/Trimethyl), we solved this issue after a long day of testing.

It's a very strange bug, but you solve it with a single line of CSS:

`<style>body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;}</style>`

Source: https://github.com/CaffeinaLab/Trimethyl/blob/master/framework/weballoy.js#L60